# Replace a line in a text file

Tags: bash, file, shell, sed

I've a text file with a line

```
default_color acolor
```

and I want to replace this line with

```
default_color anothercolor
```

I don't know the first color and the second is contained in a variable.
How can I do it in bash ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not pure bash but if you have other console tools, try something like

```
cat your_file | sed "s/default_color\ .*/default_color\ $VAR/"
```

Comment: Why do you cat? Just sed it.

Comment: it works ! thank you
I just use "sed "s/default_color\ .*/default_color\ $VAR/" file > newfile"

Comment: You don't need the redirection if you want to change the file; use the -i switch for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk. The manual entry is here:

http://ss64.com/bash/awk.html

I won't write the regular expression necessary, as that will depend on your color format, but this will fit the bill. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

use gawk

```
awk '$2=="defaultcolor"{$2="anothercolor"}1' file
```

or just bash shell and no external commands

```
while read -r line
do
 case "$line" in 
   *defaultcolor*) line=${line/defaultcolor/anothercolor}
 esac
 echo $line
done <"file"
```

Answer (score -1):

Not really a bash solution, but you can do the replacement in-place, for any number of files, with perl:

```
perl -i -npe 's/default_color acolor/default_color another_color/' list_of_files
```